# referencia de função no php

Tags: php

Estou com um problema não consigo referenciar um metodo que esta dentro da classe:

Segue o codigo:

```
define("LOGIN","root");
define("PWD","");
//define("DB", "pj_fatec");
define("DB", "virtual");
define("SERVER","localhost");

class Conexao {

     public static $conn; 

     public function open() {               
           self::$conn = new mysqli(SERVER, LOGIN, PWD, DB);

           // Check connection
           if (self::$conn->connect_error) {
                die("Connection failed: " . self::$conn->connect_error);
           } 

     }
     static function getconexao(){
         if(self::$conn){
             return self::$conn;                    
         }else{
             $this->open();
             return self::$conn;            
        }                
     }      
 }
```

Comment: Provavelmente é porque você está referenciando um objeto `$this` dentro de uma função estática, que pode ser acessada diretamente pela classe.

Comment: o problema consiste em usar o método open() sem this e com da problemas.

Comment: Neste caso você tem que alterar a função `open()` para static e chamar `self::open()` na segunda função.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá o método estático deve definir a propriedade estática para que a mesma fique visível, tente assim:

```
define("LOGIN","root");
define("PWD","");
//define("DB", "pj_fatec");
define("DB", "virtual");
define("SERVER","localhost");

class Conexao {

    public static $conn = null;

    static function getconexao(){
        self::$conn = (self::$conn===null ? new mysqli(SERVER, LOGIN, PWD, DB):self::$conn);
        if (!self::$conn) {
            die("Connection failed: " . var_dump(self::$conn));
        }
        return self::$conn;                         
    }
}
```